# Swift 4: How to compare doubles to another?

Tags: swift

i have 3 `Doubles`, their values are random, and i am trying to achieve a comparison between them

so my code is

```
let double1 = 10.00 // notes: they're all random between 1-100 so i don't know what this will be
let double2 = 7.66
let double3 = 6.43
```

but, i tried

```
 if (double1?.isLess(than: 50.0))! {
            print("Low")
        } else {
            print("High")

        }
```

but as i mentioned, this can't be done due to the random values, i need to compare two of them to each other, to make sure that one of them will be higher

Comment: Do you mean you want the maximum?

Comment: oh, i want the higher one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually rather very simple:

```
let maxDouble = max(max(double1, double2), double3) // prints 10
```

Comment: genius, life saver

Comment: Simpler: `max(double1, double2, double3)`

Comment: @MartinR: dah, I was not aware of this function. I agree its much simpler.